# rightmark without subsection?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Does anyone know how using `\documentclass{article}` and `\pagestyle{fancy}` to define the header to display only `\section` and not `\subsection`?

Fancy I defined as follows:

```
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO, LE]{\small\emph{My book}}
\fancyhead[RO, RE]{\small\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
\fancyfoot[RO, RE]{\thepage}
```

and I have defined `\sectionmark`

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{}{\emph{\thesection \#1}}}
```

I am not able to do that which page is used in the text `\subsection` was only `\section` to header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You need to remove the `\subsectionmark` functionality as well;
- Using `\#1` is incorrect, since it literally translates to printing `#1` in the header.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO, LE]{\small\emph{My book}}
\fancyhead[RO, RE]{\small\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
\fancyfoot[RO, RE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{}{\emph{\thesection~#1}}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}% Remove \subsection from header

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[3]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `article` class with the `twoside` option, `\section` sets the leftmark and `\subsection` the rightmark.

You thus need to change this default behavior or just use `\leftmark`. In this case, however, the header will reflect the section starting on a given page. It's up to you to decide what behavior you prefer.

The input can also be simplified as shown below. Formatting instructions like `\emph` belong in `\fancyhead` or `\fancyfoot` rather than `\markboth` or `\markright`.

I left the setting with `\leftmark`; switch the comments to use `\rightmark`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[L]{\small\emph{My book}}
% first possibility: use the leftmark
\fancyhead[R]{\small\emph{\leftmark}}
% second possibility: use the rightmark
%\fancyhead[R]{\small\emph{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

% first possibility: use the leftmark
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection~#1}{}}

% second possibility: use the rightmark
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[3]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```